# Cauchy and non-Cauchy sequences

Tags: real-analysis

I have this problem for my analysis class.

> Find an example of a sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that an is Cauchy and $\{na_n\}$ is non-Cauchy.

My first thought is to find a Cauchy sequence whose product is noncauchy. I’ve come up with a bunch of Cauchy ( converging and bounded) sequences but I can’t find one to fit. I could use some help.

Comment: How about $a_n=1/\sqrt n$?

Comment: Another easy possibility is $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}n$.